# Segregate data under different schema in Memorystore Redis (GCP)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I have different categories of data, for example car from multiple manufacturers Hyundai, Honda, Maruti, Tesla, Kia, BMW, Audi and so on. I would like to store few details like name, capacity, color as value in Redis and consider the key as unique identifier.

I can save this dataset using:

```
key = 12345
value = {"Name": "i30", "manufacturer": "Hyundai", "capacity": "2.0", "color": "Red"}
redis_client.set(key, prod_value)
```

Or I can formulate my key as Hyundai:12345.

But, is there any way I can **group all the Hyundai cars under** one schema like we can do using partitioning in tables? If yes, does this increase the retrieval performance?

Comment: Can you please extend about " group all" ? do you mean want a query that aggregate all the "Hyundai cars "?

Comment: @GuyKorland The idea is to only look under a specific group since I will have this information. Also, would I get any increase in performance by doing so ?

Comment: It feels like you might need a secondary index, did you consider adding RediSearch?

Comment: No, I was using redis library. This is how my get looks like.  
`import redis  

redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port='6379')  
carDetails = redis_client.get('30263844')  
print(carDetails) `

Comment: You can just create a new schema and take only the specific data that you need and depends but if it does not need to have more reads the performance would be improved but do not expect a lot.